# Extracting XML elements with default namespacing using Xpath in R

Tags: python, r, xml, xpath

I have this XML where i want to extract the *TITLE* element:

```
<BOOK xmlns="urn:example.microsoft.com:BookInfo">
  <TITLE>Creepy Crawlies</TITLE>
  <PRICE currency="US Dollar">22.95</PRICE>
</BOOK>
```

Based on the structure i would guess that the correct path would be //TITLE or /BOOK/TITLE. However, this does not return the expected element/node. This returns nothing - which makes me believe that the xpath is incorrect.

Attempting to do this in R using package XML v3.99-0.3

```
xml <- xmlParse(somexml.xml)
df  <- getNodeSet(xml, "//TITLE")
```

Returns

> dim(df)
> NULL

Removing the xmlns declaration resolves the problem. Therefore, what does a blank namespacing change and what is the problem with this logic?

Comment: Why is the question tagged [python]?

Comment: Because the same issue can be experienced in Python aswell. I've just showed it in R but i could have done the same in Python. The root cause is located in xpath